# Start Terminal application as separate app

Tags: macos, plist

I want to use WeeChat on my MacBook. In a dream world I want to be able to launch it using Spotlight, and then preferably it will open a Terminal window that is not tied to Terminal. When I Command + Tab it will have its own separate icon. It would be preferable to have it act as if it is another application than Terminal, as I usually have a lot of Terminal windows open.

I assume I have to write custom plist-files (if it is even possible), but I am kind of stuck currently.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

You could download something like iTerm - it's a different (free) application entirely that acts as a terminal replacement with different UI options. In my experience it behaves exactly like Terminal with its own configuration, so it might be easier than creating a special instance.

Comment: That is not the solution I was hoping for. If there is no other way I will probably end up full-screening it on a separate desktop.